# Conversion from `XPathNodeIterator` to `linq`

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am updating some old code of mine and decided to change everything XML related from XPath to Linq (So learn linq meanwhile). I came across this code, Can someone please tell me how to translate this to a linq statement?

```
var groups = new List<string>();
XPathNodeIterator it = nav.Select("/Document//Tests/Test[Type='Failure']/Groups/Group/Name");

foreach (XPathNavigator group in it)
{
    groups.Add(group.Value);
}
```

Comment: `XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(...);` `var groups = xDoc.Descendants("Name").Select(n => n.Value).ToList();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a rough and ready example of getting the `Group` names via LINQ:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var f = XElement.Parse("<root><Document><Tests><Test Type=\"Failure\"><Groups><Group><Name>Name 123</Name></Group></Groups></Test></Tests></Document></root>");

            var names =
                f.Descendants("Test").Where(t => t.Attribute("Type").Value == "Failure").Descendants("Group").Select(
                    g => g.Element("Name").Value);

            foreach (var name in names)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(name);    
            }
        }
```

Personally this is the kind of code I always like to write unit tests for, giving certain XML and expecting certain values in return.

Answer (score 2):

```
XPathNodeIterator it = nav.Select("/Document//Tests/Test[Type='Failure']/Groups/Group/Name");
var groups = (from XPathNavigator @group in it select @group.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks but did you get this also from ReSharper :D ?!!? I want it a bit more human friendly!